# Hibernate starts slow on local dev machine - 1 minute delay between two DEBUG log lines

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hikaricp, oracle-xe

- When I start a spring boot application with Hikari since some months it takes over a minute for startup.
- I use an OracleXE on my local machine

Logoutput with `com.zaxxer: TRACE`

```
2021-01-05 17:21:17.187  INFO 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-01-05 17:21:17.192  WARN 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2021-01-05 17:21:17.192 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Driver class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver found in Thread context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@3339ad8e
2021-01-05 17:21:17.557  INFO 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.getNetworkTimeout()I)
2021-01-05 17:21:17.560 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@220cda54
2021-01-05 17:21:17.562  INFO 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-01-05 17:21:17.596  INFO 24412 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
2021-01-05 17:21:17.664 DEBUG 24412 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=1, active=1, idle=0, waiting=0)
2021-01-05 17:21:17.664 DEBUG 24412 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - After cleanup  stats (total=1, active=1, idle=0, waiting=0)
2021-01-05 17:21:17.691 DEBUG 24412 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@193c4d19
2021-01-05 17:21:17.713 DEBUG 24412 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@17fba04e
2021-01-05 17:21:17.736 DEBUG 24412 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@13c42669
2021-01-05 17:21:17.760 DEBUG 24412 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@56c6aa75
2021-01-05 17:21:17.785 DEBUG 24412 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@2de97131
2021-01-05 17:21:17.806 DEBUG 24412 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@67da5d12
2021-01-05 17:21:17.829 DEBUG 24412 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@551fd8ee
2021-01-05 17:21:17.852 DEBUG 24412 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@50efda2f
2021-01-05 17:21:17.873 DEBUG 24412 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@65e83fed
2021-01-05 17:21:17.895 DEBUG 24412 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@4e1b5316
2021-01-05 17:21:17.896 DEBUG 24412 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - After adding stats (total=11, active=1, idle=10, waiting=0)
2021-01-05 17:21:47.667 DEBUG 24412 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=11, active=1, idle=10, waiting=0)
2021-01-05 17:21:47.667 DEBUG 24412 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - After cleanup  stats (total=11, active=1, idle=10, waiting=0)
2021-01-05 17:21:47.667 DEBUG 24412 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.

// what happens in this minue? ??????????????????????

2021-01-05 17:21:58.940  WARN 24412 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder       : HHH000138: Mixing inheritance strategy in a entity hierarchy is not allowed, ignoring sub strategy in: org.account.AccountEntity
2021-01-05 17:22:03.225  INFO 24412 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-01-05 17:22:03.238  INFO 24412 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'core'
```

I did not remember that I changed anything.

Here are the **settings** if this could be an issue:

```
2021-01-05 17:21:17.180  WARN 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - idleTimeout is less than 10000ms, setting to default 600000ms.
2021-01-05 17:21:17.181 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - configuration:
2021-01-05 17:21:17.183 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : allowPoolSuspension.............false
2021-01-05 17:21:17.183 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : autoCommit......................true
2021-01-05 17:21:17.183 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : catalog.........................none
2021-01-05 17:21:17.183 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionInitSql...............none
2021-01-05 17:21:17.183 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTestQuery.............none
2021-01-05 17:21:17.183 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTimeout...............30000
2021-01-05 17:21:17.183 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSource......................none
2021-01-05 17:21:17.184 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceClassName.............none
2021-01-05 17:21:17.184 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceJNDI..................none
2021-01-05 17:21:17.185 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : driverClassName................."oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
2021-01-05 17:21:17.185 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : exceptionOverrideClassName......none
2021-01-05 17:21:17.185 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckProperties...........{}
2021-01-05 17:21:17.185 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckRegistry.............none
2021-01-05 17:21:17.185 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : idleTimeout.....................600000
2021-01-05 17:21:17.185 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : initializationFailTimeout.......1
2021-01-05 17:21:17.185 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : isolateInternalQueries..........false
2021-01-05 17:21:17.186 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
2021-01-05 17:21:17.186 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : leakDetectionThreshold..........120000
2021-01-05 17:21:17.186 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maxLifetime.....................1800000
2021-01-05 17:21:17.186 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maximumPoolSize.................20
2021-01-05 17:21:17.186 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricRegistry..................none
2021-01-05 17:21:17.186 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricsTrackerFactory...........none
2021-01-05 17:21:17.186 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : minimumIdle.....................10
2021-01-05 17:21:17.186 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
2021-01-05 17:21:17.186 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : readOnly........................false
2021-01-05 17:21:17.186 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : registerMbeans..................false
2021-01-05 17:21:17.187 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : scheduledExecutor...............none
2021-01-05 17:21:17.187 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : schema..........................none
2021-01-05 17:21:17.187 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : threadFactory...................internal
2021-01-05 17:21:17.187 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : transactionIsolation............default
2021-01-05 17:21:17.187 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : username........................"user"
2021-01-05 17:21:17.187 DEBUG 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : validationTimeout...............5000
2021-01-05 17:21:17.187  INFO 24412 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

**Update after comments**

- I set everything to TRACE. But now this time between logging is even faster ;-), just 10 seconds. If I turn it back it's 30 seconds.
- Between the two lines there are a lot of log outputs of `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.NormalizingIdentifierHelperImpl`

log

```
 [2m2021-01-06 09:26:26.172[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13048[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[l-1 housekeeper][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
--start of long wait time
[2m2021-01-06 09:26:34.161[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m13048[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[main][0;39m [36m.e.j.e.i.NormalizingIdentifierHelperImpl[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Normalizing identifier quoting [null]
[2m2021-01-06 09:26:37.903[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m13048[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[main][0;39m [36m.e.j.e.i.NormalizingIdentifierHelperImpl[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Normalizing identifier quoting [null]
[2m2021-01-06 09:26:37.903[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m13048[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[main][0;39m [36m.e.j.e.i.NormalizingIdentifierHelperImpl[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Normalizing identifier quoting [null]
[2m2021-01-06 09:26:37.903[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m13048[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[main][0;39m [36m.e.j.e.i.NormalizingIdentifierHelperImpl[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Normalizing identifier quoting [AUDIT_TRAIL$_SEQ]
[2m2021-01-06 09:26:37.904[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m13048[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[main][0;39m [36m.e.j.e.i.NormalizingIdentifierHelperImpl[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Normalizing identifier quoting [null]
...
...
[2m2021-01-06 09:26:37.943[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m13048[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[main][0;39m [36mo.h.s.i.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing service [role=org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.JdbcServices]
[2m2021-01-06 09:26:37.947[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13048[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[main][0;39m [36mo.h.boot.model.relational.Namespace     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Created database namespace [logicalName=Name{catalog=null, schema=null}, physicalName=Name{catalog=null, schema=null}]
[2m2021-01-06 09:26:37.953[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13048[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[main][0;39m [36mo.h.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Scoping TypeConfiguration [org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration@261b6c8c] to MetadataBuildingContext [org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuildingContextRootImpl@2dcbf825]
--end of long wait time
[2m2021-01-06 09:26:38.054[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m13048[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000138: Mixing inheritance strategy in a entity hierarchy is not allowed, ignoring sub strategy in: com.core.domain.account.AccountEntity
```

So it looks like hibernate NormalizingIdentifierHelperImpl is taking all the time. There were no Spring traces in between.

Comment: Is there a FlyWay script taking time, maybe? You should enable Spring TRACE log level to see what's going on.

Comment: For starters disable debug logging (logging is slow). What is happening is that hibernate is trying to do a lot of things like reading metadata from your database. This is slow, especially on oracle. add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false` should help, also explicitly specifying the dialect to use will also help.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. thanks. also with TRACE there were only hibernate between long running logs. There was no flyway script running, i run with `ddl-auto: create-drop`. I updated my initial post.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks. Yes usually I just run with DEBUG for my own classes so well with TRACE it was slow (but the questionable time was even faster with TRACE). I tried use_jdbc_metadata_defaults to false but there was no time difference. I updated my post